# How can I protect my home?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend and I own an Attack of the B-team server and we want to make it public. Since it's an Attack of the B-team server, we can't install any plugins.

We've spent a fair amount of time building our house and we don't want it to be raided when we make it public. We thought of building a bedrock wall surrounding it, but that would obviously take a very long time.

How can we quickly do this? Or better yet, how can we protect our house from raiding when we make it public, without using any plugins?

Comment: if you have access to the worlds data you can copy out the schematic of your house and move it somewhere else.

Comment: Mcedit for the wall and two command blocks that only teleport you

Comment: Perhaps you could try running an MCPC+ server.  It has access to both the Bukkit and Minecraft Forge APIs, though some mods (such as Tinker's Construct) have warnings against it as it "may cause problems."  Then you could just use any normal world guard plugin.

Comment: Have someone else use plugins for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Without Plugins, the only way would be to use a Bedrock wall around the base and use teleporting to get inside. There is no way to create a safe area (Correct me if I am wrong) without the use of mods.

Comment: @kingbluesapphire MCEDIT won't load the world due to it being a modded one.

Comment: Yes it will, use the beta version. Any unrecognised blocks are just "Future block!"

Comment: You can use barriers instead of bedrock as of 1.8, avoiding the ugly look.

Answer (score 2):

You can use command blocks to detect players and telleport them out of a region. You need a fast clock constantly running a command to check for players and telleport them out of the area. Alternatively you could change any player in the area to adventure mode, preventing them from causing much harm.

You can exempt yourself from this most easily by adding yourself to a team, and only effecting people who are not on that team.

Answer (score 1):

The first method would be to set the gamemmode to adventure, if possible.

The second, to build the house exactly in the spawn area of the world and alter the spawn protection in the server.properties is currently the only to prevent griefers locally without the use of command blocks and clocks.

The third and most usefull will be to wait for the 1.8 update, as it will offer indestructable and fully transparent barrier-blocks. (sth like transparent bedrock)
One cant pass it without using creative commands.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Barrier

Comment: ATB won't be updated any time soon, and most likely will go to 1.7.10, not 1.8.

Comment: 1.7.10 was already out as i wrote my answer ;)
Mojang is releasing more and more snapshots in a pretty high frequency, so yes - I think they're releasing 1.8 pretty soon.
If you comment something please refer to at least one source.
I dont like answers like "nope, youre wrong."

Comment: Yeah, but ATB hasn't updated to it yet. Modded minecraft doesn't update as fast as regular one ([ATB is tekkit](http://www.technicpack.net/attack-of-the-bteam)). Also, one of the mojang staff tweeted that it would be a few months until 1.8. I don't remember which one and it was a week or two ago and I just got off a 12 hour shift so I can't find it, I'll find it tomorrow.

Comment: Well, this is something i didnt mention ^^
Its your point sir, got you an upvote :/